# Google Place Picker Fatal Error?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm getting a fatal error with this code. Any help would be appreciated.It seems the animation back to the Google Map causes it but unsure why....

```
@IBAction func showPlacePicker(sender: AnyObject) {

    // The code snippet below shows how to create a GMSPlacePicker
    // centered on self, and output details of a selected place.

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.7778640, -122.4368020)
        let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + 0.001, center.longitude + 0.001)
        let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - 0.001, center.longitude - 0.001)
        let viewport = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)
        let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: viewport)
        placePicker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)

        placePicker?.pickPlaceWithCallback({ (place: GMSPlace?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return

            }

                if let place = place {
                    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(place.coordinate.latitude, place.coordinate.longitude)
                    let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinates)
                    marker.title = place.name
                    marker.map = self.googleMapView
                    self.googleMapView.animateToLocation(coordinates)


            } else {
                print("No place was selected")

                          }




            })


}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question, and add the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out why the Places API crashes when sending a marker back to Google Maps. The print output works and then the animate to location crashes the API. Anyone?

Comment: Finally fixed this. The above Place Picker code has googleMapView as the map. In View Did Load the Map was called mapView. Both were wrong and when changed uniformly MapView, everything worked as it should.